# List text box in paramaters of function

Tags: c#, asp.net, function

I am wondering why I can't put a list of text box in parameter in my functions even if i'm using a list ...

```
 public void ClearTextBox(List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox> listTextBox)
    {            
        foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox TextBox in listTextBox)
        {
            TextBox.Text = "";
        }
    }
```

I would like to be able to do ClearTextBox(txt1,txt2,txt3);

Can someone help me please ?

Cheers

Comment: I don't have any error, I just can't put more than one textbox in parameter ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use params.

```
public void ClearTextBox(params System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox[] textBoxes)
{
   foreach(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox textBox in textBoxes)            
       textBox.Text = "";
}
```

Now you can call the method like this:

```
ClearTextBox(txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call should be like this:

```
 ClearTextBox(new List<TextBox> { textBox1, textBox2 });
```